# Goroutines with time.Sleep work, but WaitGroup causes errors - Synchronization Issue?

Tags: go, asynchronous, channel, goroutine

I am trying to synchronise 2 goroutines, like gr1 and gr2 run alternately.
For this I am using 2 channels to coordinate.

When I am using `time.Sleep` to wait for goroutines to complete, it is working without any error.

While when I use `sync.Waitgroup` to wait for goroutines it is throwing deadlock error.

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x14000002101?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:62 +0x2c
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x1027bd710)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:116 +0x74
```

### Program with time.Sleep

[go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/Wa3HQhD_EBz)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ch1, ch2 := make(chan int, 1), make(chan int, 1)

    go f1(ch1, ch2)
    go f2(ch2, ch1)

    ch1 <- 1
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
}

func f1(ch1, ch2 chan int) {
    for i := 1; i < 5; i++ {
        num := <-ch1
        fmt.Println("f1", num*i)
        ch2 <- num * i
    }
}

func f2(ch2, ch1 chan int) {
    for i := 1; i < 5; i++ {
        num := <-ch2
        fmt.Println("f2", num*i)
        ch1 <- num * i
    }
}
```

### Program with Waitgroup

[go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/oF-JMnPg5vF)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {

    ch1, ch2 := make(chan int), make(chan int)

    wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    go f1(ch1, ch2)
    go f2(ch2, ch1)

    ch1 <- 1
    wg.Wait()
}

func f1(ch1, ch2 chan int) {
    for i := 1; i < 5; i++ {
        num := <-ch1
        fmt.Println("f1", num*i)
        ch2 <- num * i
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func f2(ch2, ch1 chan int) {
    for i := 1; i < 5; i++ {
        num := <-ch2
        fmt.Println("f2", num*i)
        ch1 <- num * i
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

> For buffered channel there will be no error.

I like to understand what waitgroup is doing different than the time.sleep.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  In the question, you write "For buffered channel there will be no error"; so why are you asking about WaitGroup?  I haven't tested it, but it seems pretty clear that the version with Sleep will also deadlock with an unbuffered channel and the issue is not WaitGroup at all.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the version with `Sleep` doesn't deadlock because `main` isn't blocked.  `main`- and  thus the process - ends after two seconds, silently terminating remaining `f2` goroutine as it waits to `ch1<-num*i` one last time.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes for buffered channel it has space. Even if there is no active goroutine it will work. Thanks erik258 You can add your comment as answer. It cleared my doubt

Answer (score 1):

In the waitgroup example, you've provided, in `f2` func and in the last iteration `ch1 <- num * i` tries to write into ch1, while there is no reader available for that channel, and since it's an unbuffered channel:

> A receive from an unbuffered channel is synchronised before the completion of the corresponding send on that channel. (https://go.dev/ref/mem#chan)

Since `f2` is stalled on that line it never reaches `wg.Done()` and `wg.Wait` throws a deadlock panic.

Changing f2 as so can fix the issue while there are better options:

```golang
func f2(ch2, ch1 chan int) {
    for i := 1; i < 5; i++ {
        num := <-ch2
        fmt.Println("f2", num*i)
        if i < 4 {
            ch1 <- num * i
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```